# Update multiple rows of one column based on primary key in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

I know that I want to update only one row from a column I use this statement

```
UPDATE Customers
    SET ContactName = 'Alfred Schmidt'
    WHERE CustomerID = 1;
```

but what if I want to update multiple for example 5 rows based on primary key value?

Comment: Then you would use `IN` rather than `=`.

Comment: For future reference: please add the tag for the RDBMS you are using (sql-server, mysql, oracle, ..), as some commands are product specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `IN` operator allows you to specify multiple values in a `WHERE` clause.

Example:

As in this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers
WHERE Customer_id IN (5000, 7000, 8000, 9000);
```

format:

```
expression IN (value1, value2, .... value_n);
```

In the mentioned case :

```
UPDATE Customers
    SET ContactName = 'Alfred Schmidt'
    WHERE CustomerID IN(12, 156);
```

Comment: thank you, end how can i update different contact names in primary key positions? for example in value12 i want the name alfred and in position 133 i want the name nick..

Comment: Just put the table name you have them in and the names in parenthesis that you need in quotes.

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: @OuamerPanagiotis If you want to update different rows with different values, the easiest way would be to run multiple update commands, one for each value